# How to find reflection of $(a,b)$ along $y=x, y = -x$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

How to find reflection of $(a,b)$ along $y=x, y = -x$

I know for $y=x$ it is $(b,a)$ and for $y=-x$ it is $(-b,-a)$. But how to prove it?

[generic Qn so which tag to include do not know]

Comment: To begin with, what is your definition of “reflection?”

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just use Basic Linear Algebra for instance just write the matrix of the transformation(Reflection in this case) with a usual basis in both the cases, then it will be very clear to you that you are just supposed to operate that matrix and obtain the desired result.

Comment: Sir can u pls elaborate? I tried but it is getting messy. Took perpendicular distance to y=x.

Comment: @anirudhb just take usual basis and find the corresponding matrix of the transformation by writing the coordinate of image of the basis vectors as the columns of the matrix .